# Volley, BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 405, while making StringRequest

Tags: android, android-volley

Using Volley, I POST StringRequest and i am getting error when i am accessing the url, as it is

```
https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=vX8jVdTvOsOq8weigYHICA&gws_rd=cr&fg=1
```

But when is use **http** instead of **https** above, it won't give error and working well.

cookie and client code is below,

```
 DefaultHttpClient client_R = new DefaultHttpClient();
    RequestQueue queue_R = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, new HttpClientStack(client_R));
        CookieStore store_R = client_R.getCookieStore();
        Cookie cookie_R = new BasicClientCookie("Example_Cookie", "80");
        store_R.addCookie(cookie_R);
```

below is logcat output,

```
[199] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 405 for https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=TX4jVcChFaTj8wehzoCgCw&gws_rd=cr&fg=1
```

Why it is giving error ? With some URLs having **https**, it is working instead.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using a **POST** api request for a **GET** request. 
In your StringRequest Method use GET instead of POST.

```
StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, String url, Listener<String> listener, ErrorListener errorListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use an SSL client for your https request.
Your 405 error code is a "Method Not Allowed" error: [see more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_SIP_response_codes#405)

To use https, i use an OkHttpClient with a TrustManager.

Comment: @Alexis Burgos : Is there no possibility to use volley for a https request?

Comment: I got this problem weeks ago with Android Marshmallow. The fault was server-side (too old certificate).
I use HTTPS on my app (for subscription an password recovery) with OkHttp.
I just use 2 different client (1 for http and 1 for https with SSL factory).